# Django : error in importing the url file of an app

Tags: python, django

I am newbie in django framework

My project urls.py has the following code

```
        from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
        from django.contrib import admin
        admin.autodiscover()

        urlpatterns = patterns('',
             url(r'^rango/$',include(rango.urls)), #my test appliaction
             url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        )
```

I have created an app called [rango](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/setup.html) , that i have imported in the main project url file.

Now it throwing the following error, when I am trying to access url .../rango/
                        `Exception Value:     name 'rango' is not defined`

I can see that in that python path is not correctly set up.

This is the directory structure of my project

```
           project/
                   project/__init__.py
                   project/urls.py

                   rango/__init__.py
```

valuable advice required.

Comment: Did you add rango to your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: You need to add `import rango` in your `urls.py`.

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert that wouldn't help in any way at all. This is a NameError caused, as Omid says, by not having imported the name `rango`.

Comment: as long as `rango` is in installed apps, just do `include('rango.urls')`

Comment: Another way in your `urls.py` is possible by changing pattern of  `include(rango.urls)` to `include('rango.urls')`. in this way, you don't need to import `rango`

Comment: @j.Ghyllebert : ya I have added that to INSTALLED_APPS tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url(r'^rango/$',include(rango.urls)),
```

should read:

```
url(r'^rango/',include('rango.urls')),
```

No `$` and use quotes `'rango.urls'`. Because rango without the quotes is not defined.